# Private NS propagation

Tags: dns, nameserver

I have a client that asked me to move his domains to a new private server, this is my first experience on using private name servers so I am unsure if I am doing something incorrectly.

According to what I have read, at my registrar I have to register the private name servers, in this case ns1.vetology.net and ns2.vetology.net which I have done last Wednesday and testing the name servers they are pointing to the correct IP

- http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=NS1.VETOLOGY.NET&type=nameserver
- http://reports.internic.net/cgi/whois?whois_nic=NS2.VETOLOGY.NET&type=nameserver

So that means that Godaddy did it's job and registered the nameservers, the very same day I pointed a domain which is not in use at the moment.

dogcatmri.com to the private nameservers, since them I have been receiving a not found error on some browsers and chrome gives me a `Error 137 (net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED): Unknown error.`.

First I thought well I have to wait for both the private name servers to propagate and then the domain DNS change to propagate but since Wednesday up to today it seems a very long time for me.

Note that if I use Google DNS servers 8.8.8.8 the domain resolves, but the domain does not resolve in any other way.

So my questions is, does the fact that using Google's dns resolve the domain means that the NS servers are setup correctly and I just have to wait for propagation to complete and it is taking an awful lot of time or there is something not setup right but Google's DNS uses some other sort of domain resolution and there maybe something wrong on my setup?

This is some further testing I did, the command was run from the host machine:

```
[root@web ~]# dig dogcatmri.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.6 <<>> dogcatmri.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 60662
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dogcatmri.com.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 325 msec
;; SERVER: 4.2.2.2#53(4.2.2.2)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb 25 04:27:53 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

### Edit 1:

I am not sure if I am doing something incorrectly but my assumption is that given the following setup

> domain.com
>   domain2.com
>   server1
>   server2

So server1 is hosting `domain.com` properly
server2 is hosting `ns1.domain.com` and `ns22.domain.com`
`domain.com` has nameservers `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com`

Not moving `domain.com` to point to `ns1.domain.com` and `ns2.domain.com` will cause the other domains not to resolve or the two things are independent?

Just to clarify, my reason not to move `domain.com` at the moment is because `domain.com` is a live site and I don't want to mess with it unless I am 100% sure the server is responding as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what the problem was, basically I had added all records correctly in both server and registrar, however the fact that I did not point vetology.net to the ns1 and ns2.vetology.net servers was causing the problem, so all I had to do was add A records for ns1.vetology.net, and ns2.vetology.net in the old server to point to the new server and the sites started resolving.